# Correct way to hide parent scrollbar and only show child scrollbars

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Why am I not getting a vertical scrollbar in each div? If I use `max-h-screen` instead of `max-h-full` I'm getting the scrollbar but the problem is that - because of the navbar - the content at the bottom of the screen is clipped by exactly the height of the navbar.

[Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/JQM2u2dbqO)

```
<div class="h-screen overflow-hidden"> 
 <div class="flex flex-col">
  <div class="h-12">Navbar </div>
   <main class="flex flex-row">
    <div class=" w-1/5 flex h-full max-h-full overflow-y-auto flex-col flex-grow bg-purple-50">Lorem... </div>

   <div class=" w-4/5 bg-gray-50 h-full max-h-full overflow-y-auto">Lorem... </div>
 </main>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to carry the height: 100% onto the second nested div, and your main. Otherwise the height becomes auto and grows to accommodate your content, so on tailwind that looks like it's `h-full` you'll need to put on both of those

Answer (score 0):

You need to carry the height: 100% onto the second nested div, and your main. Otherwise the height becomes auto and grows to accommodate your content, so on tailwind that looks like it's `h-full` you'll need to put on both of those:

```html
<div class="h-screen overflow-hidden">
  <div class="flex flex-col h-full">
    <div class="h-12">Navbar </div>
    <main class="flex flex-row h-full">
      <div class=" w-1/5 flex h-full max-h-full overflow-y-auto flex-col flex-grow bg-purple-50">Lorem... </div>

      <div class=" w-4/5 bg-gray-50 h-full max-h-full overflow-y-auto">Lorem... </div>
    </main>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is a good hint but it doesn't solve it for me. I now get the scrollbars but the content still gets cropped at the bottom by the height of the Navbar.

Comment: @SPi yea idk, stick a pb-12 on them

Comment: That doesn't work for me (outside of this simplified example). I have a bunch of nested divs that have flexible heights, so it's impossible to know what total bottom padding I would need to add ...